# How can i get the text or need path to get exact text inside the tag

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I have html like the below

```
<label id ="someid"> 
some text in label <span> count(10) </span></label>
```

I need to get text inside the label.

If I use `driver.find_element_by_id('someid').text();`

I will get as `some text in label count(10)`

But I don't want to get `count(10)`.

Is there any way to write the path to get exact text available in label, not elements inside label

Answer (score 0):

This XPath will get first text node under label element :

```
//label[@id ='someid']/text()[1]
```

Given sample xml in this question, above XPath will return :

```
some text in label
```